# Redis envoy proxy

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis, envoyproxy, lettuce, redisson

I tried to set up Redis as an Envoy proxy from this example https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/tree/main/examples/redis. The problem is it does not support some commands like HELLO and INFO in Spring boot I used lettuce for connecting to this Redis and it failed because it needs the HELLO command I was able to work with redisson but its Redis health check fails because tries to use INFO command. Does anyone have any Envoy experience and how can I make it work with these libraries?

Comment: Envoy Redis Proxy works with only a subset of all Redis commands.  Some clients might use INFO, etc. to determine cluster members, etc.  These kinds of things can sometimes be configured from the client, so you should look there first to see if you can disable some of those calls or perhaps try a different client.  Otherwise, you can try to muck with the error responses from envoy, but that might get messy.